# Values not passed from ctp file to controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, shopping-cart, cakephp-3.6

I have tried several solution posted in this forum and others as well but it has not helped so far. So I am posting my question finally. BTW, I am using CakePHP 3.6.

I am trying to pass a variable (`$product->id`) via submit button in `view.ctp` to my controller action "addit" but I just get "Undefined variable: id " (I have tried `addit($id)` and `addit()` either of case I have the same result.)

**view.ctp**

```
<p>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('NULL',['url'=>['controller'=>'products','action'=>'addit']]);?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $product->id]); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->button('Add to cart now');?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>

</p>
```

**Controller:Products**

```
public function addit() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // $this->Products->addProduct($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
        echo "".$this->Products->get($id);//for test
    } else {
        echo "".$this->Products->get($id);//for test
    }
 }
```

Comment: You are sending your data using post method but trying to receive in controller using get method !!
in controller use $this->request->data($id); for post request.

Comment: thanks for your response :)... i later realised it ...and got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
$id = $this->request->getData('id');
debug($this->Products->get($id)); //for test
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Cakephp 3.6

> All POST data can be accessed using
>   Cake\Http\ServerRequest::getData(). Any form data that contains a data
>   prefix will have that data prefix removed. For example:

```
// An input with a name attribute equal to 'MyModel[title]' is accessible at
$title = $this->request->getData('MyModel.title');
```

You can get value of $id variable like this:

```
$id = $this->request->getData('id');
```

Further Reading: [Request Body Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)